# Python Web Scraping: Duplication and output display problem

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

There is a problem with my code somewhere which I tried but can't identify. It relates to the output of the loops not showing and inserting into my DB correctly.
I would like each scraped line of data print as output and then to be inserted into a database table. So far, all I get is just one result printed as a duplicate many times (doesn't even have the right price).

Actual current output:

```
Ford C-MAX 2019 1.1 Petrol 0
Ford C-MAX 2019 1.1 Petrol 0
Ford C-MAX 2019 1.1 Petrol 0
...
```

Desired output as per web page ads (just an example as it's dynamic):

```
Ford C-MAX 2019 1.1 Petrol 15950
Ford C-MAX 2014 1.6 Diesel 12000
Ford C-MAX 2011 1.6 Diesel 9000
...
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import re
import locale
import time
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
import itertools

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

pages = np.arange(0, 210, 30)

entered = datetime.now()
make = "Ford"
model = "C-MAX"


def insertvariablesintotable(make, model, year, liter, fuel, price, entered):
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', database='FYP', host='127.0.0.2', port='8000')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ford_cmax ( make VARCHAR(15), model VARCHAR(20), '
                       'year INT(4), liter VARCHAR(3), fuel VARCHAR(6), price INT(6), entered TIMESTAMP) ')

        insert_query = """INSERT INTO ford_cmax (make, model, year, liter, fuel, price, entered) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        record = (make, model, year, liter, fuel, price, entered)

        cursor.execute(insert_query, record)

        cnx.commit()

    finally:
        if (cnx.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()

for response in pages:

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get("https://www.donedeal.ie/cars/Ford/C-MAX?start=" + str(response), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', database='FYP', host='127.0.0.2', port='8000')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    for details in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'card__body-keyinfo'}):

        details = details.text
        #print(details)
        year = details[:4]
        liter = details[4:7]
        fuel = details[8:14] #exludes electric which has 2 extra
        mileage = re.findall("[0-9]*,[0-9][0-9][0-9]..." , details)
        mileage = ''.join(mileage)
        mileage = mileage.replace(",", "")
        if "mi" in mileage:
            mileage = mileage.rstrip('mi')
            mileage = round(float(mileage) * 1.609)
        mileage = str(mileage)
        if "km" in mileage:
            mileage = mileage.rstrip('km')
        mileage = mileage.replace("123" or "1234" or "12345" or "123456", "0")

    for price in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'card__price'}):

        price = price.text
        price = price.replace("No Price", "0")
        price = price.replace("123" or "1234" or "12345" or "123456", "0")
        price = price.replace(",","")
        price = price.replace("€", "")
        if "p/m" in price:
            #price = price[:-3]
            price = price.rstrip('p/m')
            price = "0"
        if "£" in price:
            price = price.replace("£", "")
            price = c.convert(price, 'GBP', 'EUR')
            price = round(price)

    print(make, model, year, liter, fuel, price)

    #insertvariablesintotable(make, model, year, liter, fuel, price, entered) #same result as above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your code and the website you're trying to get the data from and it looks like you're retrieving the page, then looping on all the prices you're getting from that page using `price` as a variable but overwriting it every time you enter the for loop. Same goes for your details `for` loop.

Here is what you could try instead:

```
make = "Ford"
model = "C-MAX"
price_list = [] # we will store prices here
details_list = [] # and details like year, liter, mileage there
for response in range(1,60,30): # I changed to a range loop for testing

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
    }
    response = requests.get(
        "https://www.donedeal.ie/cars/Ford/C-MAX?start=" + str(response),
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    count = 0
    for details in soup.findAll("ul", attrs={"class": "card__body-keyinfo"}):
        if count == 30:
            break # Takes us out of the for loop
        details = details.text
        # print(details)
        year = details[:4]
        liter = details[4:7]
        fuel = details[8:14]  # exludes electric which has 2 extra
        mileage = re.findall("[0-9]*,[0-9][0-9][0-9]...", details)
        mileage = "".join(mileage)
        mileage = mileage.replace(",", "")
        if "mi" in mileage:
            mileage = mileage.rstrip("mi")
            mileage = round(float(mileage) * 1.609)
        mileage = str(mileage)
        if "km" in mileage:
            mileage = mileage.rstrip("km")
        mileage = mileage.replace("123" or "1234" or "12345" or "123456", "0")
        details_list.append((year, liter, fuel, mileage)) # end of one loop go-through, we append
        count += 1 We update count value 
    count = 0
    for price in soup.findAll("p", attrs={"class": "card__price"}):
        if count == 30:
            break # Takes us out of the for loop
        price = price.text
        price = price.replace("No Price", "0")
        price = price.replace("123" or "1234" or "12345" or "123456", "0")
        price = price.replace(",", "")
        price = price.replace("€", "")
        if "£" in price:
            price = price.replace("£", "")
            price = c.convert(price, "GBP", "EUR")
            price = round(price)
        if "p/m" in price:
            # price = price[:-3]
            price = price.rstrip("p/m")
            price = "0"
        else:
            price_list.append(price) # end of loop go-through, we append but only if it is not a "p/m" price
            count += 1 # We update count value only when a value is appended to the list

for i in range(len(price_list)):
    print(
    make,
    model,
    details_list[i][0],
    details_list[i][1],
    details_list[i][2],
    price_list[i],
)
    #add your insertvariablesintotable(make,model,details_list[i][0], details_list[i][1],details_list[i][2],price_list[i]) there
```

Edit: I did not add the p/m prices to the list as they were making the lengths of details_list and price_list differ. If you want to add the p/m prices too, you will have to rework the code. Also, you don't want to have the 3 cars at the very bottom of the page as they might not be Ford C-MAX, but other models instead, maybe even other manufacturers.

Comment: Thank you sir, however I tried and the output I get is: ` ... 15950 ('2011', '1.6', 'Diesel')
2750 ('2018', '1.0', 'Petrol')
1 ('2017', '1.2', 'Petrol')
7950 ('2019', '1.1', 'Petrol')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xx.py", line 122, in <module>
    print(price_list[i], details_list[i])  # you can add your insert there
IndexError: list index out of range` and I also don't know how to add the insert down below, and the details are now a list rather than single variables?

Comment: The issue is that you're actually getting 33 car details per page (30 in the list + 3 at the very bottom of the page) and various number of prices because you also include the p/m prices. I will edit my answer to help you to implement that. The prices and details are indeed stored in a list.

Comment: Thank you sir! The print and insert works fine, however results still include the last 3 (different models) from each page iteration. I have my np.arange set as (0,58,29) for the first two pages and if I change this then then the url won't go scrape from the next page as page 1 is ?start=0 and page 2 is ?start=29 etc. How do i exclude the last 3 results?

Comment: Everytime you call the API, you get 33 results back, so you cannot change this behavior by tweaking the start parameter. However, what you can do is check when you have added 30 valid items in your price list (that is excluding p/m prices) and 30 valid items in your details list. See my updated answer

Comment: Almost perfect, it in fact cuts the loop after 30 but only takes the first 30 and cuts the entire program and doesn't go scraping page 2,3 etc. Any fix?

Comment: Make sure you did change `for response in range (1,60,30)` back to your `np.arrange`. Check also that the indentation of the `if` statement and the `break` so that it does not cut the main loop. The code works fine in my side and retrieves ~207 cars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213339/discussion-between-dynamia-and-niko).